# webm video, video player

Tags: webm

I have created a hyperlink in ms word for a WEBM video. The video runs in chrome. But while clicking on the hyperlink ,it asks for default video player to play in. Does not play this in windows media player. However video runs in browser but just clicking the hyperlink on word does not play this. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Webm video is an audio-video format designed for HTML5. Windows Media Player will not play .webm videos without external software - you will have to install several filters and codecs in order to get the format to work.

For a tutorial, visit this [website](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/how_to_play_webm_files_page_2.cfm).